# Ruby uniq value and sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have array of arrays

```
arr =  [
  ["BEER", 37],
  ["BEER", 95],
  ["BEER", 85],
  ["BEER", 60],
  ["BEER", 36],

  ["FOOD", 31],
  ["FOOD", 86],
  ["FOOD", 50],
  ["FOOD", 0]
]
```

How to fetch array like this

```
new_arr = [ [ 'FOOD', sum_of_food ],
            ['BEER', sum_of_beer] ]
```

I just got `arr` by `Model.all.map {|c| [c.source, c.amount ] }`

Comment: Rails != Ruby. Your problem is about Ruby, not Rails.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti i need it inside my rails app :)

Comment: @xxx It doesn't matter, it's a Ruby problem. In this case, the fact your code is within a Rails action or a Sinatra action doesn't make any difference. You manipulate an `array` with Ruby, not with Rails.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti i meant, maybe activerecord has something for my purpose

Comment: @xxx In that case is different. I updated the answer to show how to use the database to compute the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to loop each item in the collection and compute the sump into a new Array that is used as accumulator.

```
arr =  [
 ["BEER", 37],
 ["BEER", 95],
 ["BEER", 85],
 ["BEER", 60],
 ["BEER", 36],

 ["FOOD", 31],
 ["FOOD", 86],
 ["FOOD", 50],
 ["FOOD", 0],
]

arr.inject({}) do |accumulator, (what, total)|
  accumulator[what] ||= 0
  accumulator[what]  += total
  accumulator
end
```

If you need an `Array` instead of a Hash, just call `to_a` on the result.

---

If the data is stored in a database, you can query directly the database using the SQL `SUM()` statement.

```
results = Model.select('source, SUM(amount) AS total').group(:source)
result = results.first
result.source
# => FOO
result.total
# => the sum of amount for FOO
```

Comment: A variant is `arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(what, total),h| h[what]  += total }`. Regardless of whether one creates an empty hash with a default value of zero (as I have) or uses (the slightly more efficient) `accumulator[what] ||= 0`, I prefer `each_with_object` to `inject` (aka `reduce`) here, as the former does not require the accumulated value to be returned to the enumerator (the bare line `accumulator` in Simone's code). [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) has been with us since v1.9.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. That method has such a weird name that I can never remember it, that's why I generally go with `inject`. :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use three [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html) methods: `group_by`, `map` and `reduce` (aka `inject`):

```
arr.group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).reduce(:+)] }
  #=> [["BEER", 313],["FOOD", 167]]
```

The steps:

```
h = arr.group_by(&:first)
  # => {"BEER"=>[["BEER", 37], ["BEER", 95], ["BEER", 85], ["BEER", 60],
  #              ["BEER", 36]],
  #     "FOOD"=>[["FOOD", 31], ["FOOD", 86], ["FOOD", 50], ["FOOD", 0]]}
```

`map` assigns the block variables to the first<sup>1</sup> element (key-value pair) of `h`:

```
k = "BEER"
v = [["BEER", 37], ["BEER", 95], ["BEER", 85], ["BEER", 60], ["BEER", 36]]
```

then performs the block calculation:

```
[k, v.map(&:last).reduce(:+)]
  #=> ["BEER", [37, 95, 85, 60, 36].reduce(:+)]
  #   ["BEER", 313]
```

The second element of `h` is passed to the block:

```
k = "FOOD"
v = [["FOOD", 31], ["FOOD", 86], ["FOOD", 50], ["FOOD", 0]]
[k, v.map(&:last).reduce(:+)]
  #=> ["FOOD", [31, 86, 50, 0].reduce(:+)]
  #   ["FOOD", 167]
```

If the pairs of `arr` are known to be grouped by the first element of the pair, as they are in the example, we could use [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
arr.chunk(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).reduce(:+)] }
```

<sup>1 Since Ruby v1.9 hash keys are ordered by their insertion order. One therefore can refer to the nth element (key-value pair) of the hash. Before v1.9 there was no concept of hash keys being ordered. For those versions the above code works fine, but we don't know the order of the key-value pairs being passed by `map` to its block.</sup>